# How to remove names from “GitHub contribution list”

Tags: github

I fixed some minor typos from someone's GitHub repository and now, in my GitHub profile, the repository is listed as one of which I have contributed to. Is there any way to remove it from my profile?

Comment: Are you still watching the repo and do you still have a fork?

Comment: I have a fork, but I can delete it, not problem. And, I am not watching it.

Comment: Have you deleted the fork and does it remove it from your list?

Comment: I've deleted the fork, but it is still there. Showing, at the right side of the profile page, where it says: "Repositories contributed to"

Answer (score 7):

Right now the only way to "remove" your name from the "Repositories contributed to" and "Repositories you contribute to" lists is to bury it with more commits on more active projects.

The repos that show up there are based on two key ranking factors:

- Recent activity on the original repo
- Total commits by you accepted/merged into the repo

So all you need to do is commit more to other projects and do so on projects with more activity than those you want to push down.

That is until GitHub release a new feature where you can cherry pick what shows up in those two boxes.

Comment: Thanks @Eight Days. Its not the answer I wanted to hear.